# ajax text response not changing to new text

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am starting learning Ajax and following an online tutorial. i have to following script that reads a text file and changes the html title with the contents of the text file. It works at first the hml page changed from "hello world" to 555 555 which was the contents of the text file. I then updated the text file with "The world has changed" but when I click on the web page button I still get the old 555 555 being displayed. 
I have checked on another computer and the contents "the world has changed" is displayed. So I guess this is a problem with the explorer remembering the old text. 
How do I clear this cache.

EDIT
I have found that clearing the browser history will make the new text file contents display. Also alter a length of time approx 15 min the new text file contents will display with out clearing the browser history.

```
 <div id="demo">
     <h2>Hello world</h2>
 </div>

 <button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Title</button>

 <script type="text/javascript">
     function loadDoc(){
         var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
             if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200){
                 document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
             }
         };
         xhttp.open("GET", "hh.txt", true);
         xhttp.send();
     }
 </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: One possible reason is because your ajax request is not working. Open the console and check the network tab if you are working on Google Chrome. You should see the request failing, and giving you something different then a 200 status code

Comment: it did work the first time and does work on another console. On checking the network tab I am getting status 200 so it should be ok

Comment: Take into consideration that you are not using a relative path: `hh.txt`. If you want it to work on any page you have to make it relative like so: `/hh.txt`

Comment: I have done your suggestion but still i get the old text file contents. On other computers I am getting the new contents. The file is being read by the ajax but the web browser is remembering old contents. If I clear the browser data then the new contents is displayed

Comment: How are you testing it on multiple computers??

Comment: I am in an office with 3 computer on one network and a laptop on a mobile network. So I can have one with the history not cleared and the others I can clear the history to prove this is where chrome is remembering the old contents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One quick fix to disable cache would be

```
xhttp.open("GET", "hh.txt?t=" + Math.random(), true);
```

You can also try this for more unique url

```
var timestamp = new Date().getTime();

xhttp.open("GET", "hh.txt?t=" + timestamp, true);
```